# Is this something a query should handle?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to create a database to track usage, and inventory system.  Is there a way using queries to keep a running count of instances, like if 3 people each take 1 of something I can generate a report saying that 3 of that item are being used?

Comment: Unless a log is created every time someone is going to use something then it is not really possible to have a running count of the information.

Comment: depends on your table structure. If you simply note that 3 items are in use, then the best you can do is say "3 items are in use", but if you record each individual instance (as suggested by PaulFrancis) of a person using an item, then it is possible to say "1 item used by Bob, 1 by Sam, and 1 by Todd"  Show the related tables and we can give better advice. As of right now the question is pretty vague.

Comment: The question is a bit vague.. it sounds like you want to create a table that lists each individual item in your inventory, and then another table that tracks instances of that item being "checked-out" and "checked-in" to people. You'd need an interface that allows you keep the checked-in / checked-out status of item, but then yes I think you could easily write a query that shows how many items in your inventory are currently checked-out or "in use"... perhaps sketch-out the table structure a bit more and then edit your question with an example of the structure and result you're looking for.